# In linux shell script how to find 1 string and remove the 4 previous lines

Tags: regex, shell, perl, awk, sed

I would like each time in my file there is line containing pattern "yellow", it removes this line and the 4 previous lines.

Example, my file :

```
orange
green
grey
black
blue
yellow
red
green
grey
white
black
yellow
blue
```

Output file would be :

```
orange
red
blue
```

Many thanks. If possible with an unix standard command such as awk, sed, cut, grep, perl script, php script, python script... (my entry file is **VERY BIG**, almost 2Gb, 25 millions lines)

Comment: Hello. I would like some more advises on how not to get my question on hold in the future. What is the exact problem please so I can improve myself , asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac file | awk '/yellow/{p=5} !p--' | tac
orange
red
blue
```

- `tac` - concatenate and print files in reverse
- `awk` command sets a counter at 5 and skips print for next 4 lines

Comment: But rather heavy for a big file.  Processing it linearly would be more efficient, even if it is slightly more complex.

Comment: Hello Anubhava. No, if I cut and paste on my terminal, "blue" is missing in the output, I wonder why..? I only get "orange" and "red" ! Thanks! Smart way, still!

Comment: It could be due to no new line in last line of your file. Before this command run this command `echo '' >> file` and then run this command.

Comment: Ok, will try, understood, many thanks. BTW as you see they have put my question on hold I really wonder why, I would love to comply with their rule. Anyway I got big help from you and other guys, many thanks, I appreciate.

Comment: Reason why they put a hold on question because you didn't show your attempted code.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

perl from command line,

```
perl -ne'
  push @r, $_;
  @r = () if /^yellow$/;
  print eof() ? @r : @r >=5 ? shift @r : "";
' file
```

output

```
orange
red
blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
awk '{a[++c]=$1}/yellow/{for(i=1;i<=c-5;i++){print a[i]};c=0;delete a}END{for(i=1;i<=c;i++){print a[i]}}' file
```